# Ticking noise in a 2011 Corsa SXI at 54000 miles

Tags: noise, car, corsa

I currently have a 2011 Corsa SXI 1.4 Petrol sitting at 54000 miles. I recently purchased this about a month ago and had noticed that there is this mysterious ticking noise.

**Startup**
No ticking sound at all while idle or driving for the first minute or so

**While driving**

- After 1 minute of driving, the ticking noise occur
- Ticks only when at 1k-2k RPMs during slight or constant acceleration
  *(no ticks when gas pedal is **not** pressed)*
- Sound seems to be more noticeable inside the car compared to opening
  the bonnet
- Sound also occurs in neutral at 1k-2k RPMs

**Switching the Engine off**

- After a drive with ticking noises, turning the engine off and on again the ticks disappear and reappears after a minute of drive again.

During the startup, there is no ticking noises whatsoever, however after a minute of driving the ticking noise appears and only ticks when I press the gas slightly and goes away when I don't press on it. I checked the oil, seems fine.

Was wondering if anyone knows what the issue may be and how I would solve this.

***Here's a video recording of the noise it makes**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVStukYz5SA

Thankyou! :)

Comment: Two reasonably common sources of ticking sound are hydraulic valve lifters and piston slap. However, I believe it is neither. Piston slap would occur immediately after startup as well, and Paulster2 gave great explanation why it isn't hydraulic valve lifters either. One thing that can tick continuously is fuel injectors (my 1989 Opel Vectra used to have ticky injectors), but that would be continuous as well. So, this long comment is here only to say what it isn't, not to say what it is.

Comment: I just made a video and recorded the noise - would you mind checking it out to see if the noise could determine what it could possibly be the problem? (recorded under the windshield on the dashboard in front of steering wheel) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVStukYz5SA

Comment: There is a vauxhall field fix for this: https://workshop-manuals.com/vauxhall/corsa-d/j__engine_and_engine_aggregates/fuel_injection_systems/gmpt-e83/technical_service_bulletins/noise_vibration_rattle/engine_a12/14xel/r_ticking_noise_from_engine_compartment/

Answer (score 0):

With only 54k miles, the tick is most likely due to sticky hydraulic valve lifters.  I have had this problem on several cars over the years.

Solution:  Change the oil and filter with Mobil 1 (full synthetic), but substitute one quart (20%) with Marvel Mystery Oil.  If that product is unavailable in your country, use automatic transmission fluid.

You should notice an improvement after only 15 minutes of driving at highway speeds.  You can leave the fluid in the crankcase, but be sure to change the oil again after 3k miles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From the description, I'd highly doubt it's a noisy valve lifter, mainly because the noise isn't as appreciable from under the hood. If it were a lifter, you'd most likely hear it all the time, especially under the hood. I would also think you'd hear it no matter what engine speed you were running at, not just between 1-2k. If it were the issue, your suggestion of running Marvel's is not a bad one. The OP may want to try this just to see if there's any affect to the noise.

Comment: I just made a video and recorded the noise - would you mind checking it out to see if the noise could determine what it could possibly be the problem? (recorded under the windshield on the dashboard in front of steering wheel) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVStukYz5SA

Answer (score 0):

After I listened to your recording, and because you said it is more noticeable inside the car, I believe you need to look for something vibrating against the firewall or underside of the car as the engine runs.

With all the components of new cars jammed into tight spaces, many components are in close proximity to other things and can cause noise if touching. Check for any pipes, levers, cable bundles, brackets, etc.  For instance, a loose exhaust hanger/holder can allow an exhaust pipe to touch at certain times as the engine revs.

Also, check your motor mounts to ensure they are not allowing excessive engine movement.

Answer (score 0):

It’s the evap pump that sucks the vapors from the fuel tank they all do it and it goes away after 1500 rpm

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Could you elaborate on how the original poster could test for this problem, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have an identical problem with a 64 plate 1.4 SXi Corsa. According to a Vauxhall inspection it is caused by the 'tank vent valve'.

Answer (score -1):

Might also be a sticky fuel injector.  Add Marvel Mystery Oil to the gas tank at a treat rate of 1 oz. per gallon at fill-up.  Drive car for one tankful and refill at a rate of 4 oz. per 10 gallons of gas at every fill-up thereafter.

Comment: Would your solutions be ok since I live in the UK and the car is a manual petrol as well, and I don't think the car can take 10 gallons haha, so I would need to add the marvel oil in both the engine and the fuel tank?   - also, would I need to get the exact Mobil oil brand or will other fully synthetic oil brands do as well?

Comment: Marvel Mystery Oil will work on any internal combustion engine, gasoline or diesel.  If it is unavailable in your locale, it is available on eBay UK.  It can be added to the crankcase and fuel tank simultaneously or individually.  You don't need to use Mobil 1, it will work with any motor oil.  I only suggested Mobil 1 for its high detergent concentration, which enhances the cleaning effect of MM Oil (particularly during the first 48 hrs. after an oil change), so run engine hard right away.