# Ticking noise 2011 vauxhall corsa

Tags: noise, vauxhall, corsa

I currently have a 2011 Corsa SXI 1.4 Petrol sitting at 54000 miles. I recently purchased this about a month ago and had noticed that there is this mysterious ticking noise.

Startup No ticking sound at all while idle or driving for the first minute or so

While driving

After 1 minute of driving, the ticking noise occur
Ticks only when at 1k-2k RPMs during slight or constant acceleration (no ticks when gas pedal is not pressed)
Sound seems to be more noticeable inside the car compared to opening the bonnet
Sound also occurs in neutral at 1k-2k RPMs
Switching the Engine off

After a drive with ticking noises, turning the engine off and on again the ticks disappear and reappears after a minute of drive again.
During the startup, there is no ticking noises whatsoever, however after a minute of driving the ticking noise appears and only ticks when I press the gas slightly and goes away when I don't press on it. I checked the oil, seems fine.

I took it to Halfords Autocentre & they told me it is likely it is loose pistons? surely if it was that they car would loose power etc.

The car runs smooth, starts smooth etc just the ticking noise is driving me mad

thanks!

ps noise is like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVStukYz5SA
please turn up volume to hear it properly

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's hard to know what you're describing. Would you be able to upload an audio file or video of the "ticking" somewhere, perhaps with narration, and then link to it in your question?

Comment: Hi, i'ts like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVStukYz5SA

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been discussed [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/41500/ticking-noise-in-a-2011-corsa-sxi-at-54000-miles).  The best guess is that it is the evap pump that sucks vapors from the fuel tank.

I will add that I once had a car with a loose crankshaft and it did not sound at all like the noise in the link.  It was louder and more metallic.

You could change the motor oil with a heavier weight for a time and see if that affects the noise.  If no change at all, it is unlikely to be a serious mechanical issue like pistons, rods, etc.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.
I changed the oil to a much thicker oil on Friday at Halfords and the noise is still persisting. Is there any way to make it stop lol? driving me nuts